# RSelenium with Docker. Error in checkError(res)

Tags: r, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

Following documentation online for using RSelenium with Docker, I have installed Docker Toolbox and RSelenium.

In the Docker Toolbox, I run

```
$ docker run -d -p 4445:4445 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

and

```
$ docker ps,
```

and get the following output.

[image]

Then, I run the following in R:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(Rvest) #not sure if I need this?
#192.168.99.100 is my IP

remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", 
                             port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
```

but I get the error

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to 
192.168.99.100 port 4445: Connection refused
```

In Kitematic, I see this:

[image]

The only things I can think of that is causing this, is that I'm not using Toolbox correctly (need Docker for Windows instead), or that the default path in the path argument to remoteDriver() is not right.

I am running on Windows machine, but don't have Windows 10 pro.

Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: run as `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the selenium/standalone-chrome listen to the 4444 port. that's why you should to map yo 4444 port.

run as `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome`